# Are "mostly POSIX-compliant" systems still considered POSIX systems?

Tags: posix

Irix and OS X are POSIX systems because they are fully-POSIX-compliant. However, operating systems like FreeBSD, Haiku, and GNU/Linux, for example, are "mostly-POSIX-compliant". Can people still correctly refer to such systems as POSIX systems?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. The Open Group has an actual POSIX certification process, so if an operating system hasn't been through that, it cannot be referred to as POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Of course, this won't stop people from referring to them as such, and it's still a useful handle.

Comment: you mean certified, not compliant, right? Since, compliance are the standards, the certification is the officiality of it, you can be compliant, but not pay the certification fee, you may not legally say that tho, but for all intents and purposes compliance, just means passes the test, then again distros are responsible for that.